# Dispatchevent not working in native extension for ios

Tags: addeventlistener, air-native-extension, dispatchevent, custom-events

I've build a native extension for my project to fire two event about login and logout,this is code (NdPlatformExtension.as), the extIntance for singleton have tried but get same result,so ignore it.

```
private static const API_LOGIN_CALL:String = "LogIn";
private static const API_LOGOUT_CALL:String = "LogOut";
private static const EXTENSION_ID:String = "NdPlatformExt";     

public var extContext:ExtensionContext; 

private static var extIntance:NdPlatformExtension = null; 

public function NdPlatformExtension()
{           
  extContext = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext(EXTENSION_ID,"");        
  extContext.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,onEvent);
}

public static function get ExtInstance():NdPlatformExtension {
  if(extIntance == null) {
    extIntance = new NdPlatformExtension(); 
  } 
  return extIntance;
}

public function onEvent(e:StatusEvent):void { 
  ConsoleLog(e.code);
  switch(e.code)            
  {             
    case NdPlatformEvent.EVENT_API_LOGIN_RESULT:
    {
      ConsoleLog("event dispatch start");                       
      var _succed:Boolean = dispatchEvent(new NdPlatformEvent(NdPlatformEvent.EVENT_API_LOGIN_RESULT,e.level.split('|')));
      _succed = dispatchEvent(new NdPlatformEvent(NdPlatformEvent.EVENT_API_TEST,null));
      ConsoleLog(_succed);//i've been checked on the log the _succed is true
    }
    break;  
    default:
    {
      dispatchEvent(new NdPlatformEvent(NdPlatformEvent.EVENT_API_LOGIN_RESULT,null));
    }
    break;
  }                 
} 

public function LogIn():String {
  var _result:String = ""; 
  try
  {
    _result = extContext.call(API_LOGIN_CALL) as String;
  }
  catch(_e:Error)
  {
    _result = _e.message;               
  }
  return _result;   
}   

public function LogOut():String {
  var _result:String = ""; 
  try
  {
    _result = extContext.call(API_LOGOUT_CALL) as String;
  }
  catch(_e:Error)
  {
    _result = _e.message;               
  }
  return _result;   
}
}
}
```

And build a test flex project to listen the custom events, but all listeners I added are not fire. Here the view file content,the listener will add in view creationComplete.

```
...creationComplete="init()" title="Test">
  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import NdPlatformExt.NdPlatformEvent;
        import NdPlatformExt.NdPlatformExtension;

        import flash.events.Event;

        private var ext:NdPlatformExtension = new NdPlatformExtension();


        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void

        {       
            ext.LogIn();    
        }   

        protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void

        {           

        }           

        public function init():void
        {
            ext.addEventListener(NdPlatformEvent.EVENT_API_LOGIN_RESULT,onLoginResult,true);    
            ext.addEventListener(NdPlatformEvent.EVENT_API_TEST,onTest,true);
        }

        public function onLoginResult(_event:NdPlatformEvent):void{
            ext.ConsoleLog("event receive ok");
            ext.LogOut();
        }


        public function onTest():void{
            ext.ConsoleLog("test receive ok");
        }

    ]]>

</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label id="output" x="14" y="70" width="300" height="32" text=""/>
<s:Button x="44" y="19" width="231" label="Login"
          click="button1_clickHandler(event)" alignmentBaseline="ideographicCenter"/>

<s:Button x="44" y="111" width="231" label="Purchase"
          click="button2_clickHandler(event)" alignmentBaseline="ideographicCenter"/>
```

but all listener i added are not fire.

Comment: This code all looks reasonable. I think you'll have to check your native code to see that you are dispatching a status event from the native side as this is what your extension is listening for.